# iPhone app opens to black screen after refactor proj name in xCode 4

Tags: iphone

Guys, i wonder if any one can help - My project was fully working in both the simulator and on a device, however, i renamed the project in xcode 4 (double clicking at the root of the project navigation pane, it was happy to rename any references - but now when i launch the app it only opens to the main window (yes it has outlets, all have outlets etc etc),

no code in the app delegate stops at a break point (even in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions)

so unsure what i could have missed, i have looked at other answers and everyone writes and says "missing outlet" etc.

I have dragged some backed up version of the app delegate that used to work and no difference, what could i be missing.

I do have source control, however currently in the process of merging from VSS to GIT.

thanks

lee

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your Info.plist for what it uses as it's Main Nib File. Perhaps something changed there? Also, within the nib file itself you might have problematic connections to classes that are still named with the old name.

Comment: will be having a look first thing tomorrow, i havent checked the plist  for the main nib so hopefully thats the problem.. i will let you know, cheers

Comment: You should check the console to see what errors (if any) you are getting. Did your main app delegate get renamed in the refactor? If so, the nib for MainWindow might be trying to get an instance of the old class. This should show up in the console in one way or another though.

Comment: no luck - i got that fed up, i created a new project and moved all my classes over etc and now works fine, i have kept the old knackered one though, I would be interested to look later as to what I (or the refactor) managed to 'break' - cheers for your help though